# Is it possible to have a variable number of conditions in a while loop?

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to place objects onto the screen, and after each object is placed, I'm using a while loop to keep replacing the next object until it doesn't overlap with any of the previous objects, then if there are too many tries I stop drawing there.

The problem is that the number of conditions in the while loop needs to increase after each object is placed, so I was wondering if there was some sort of method, similar to using summations instead of addition?

Edit:

All of this code is contained within another for loop for each `i` less than the maximum number of objects. I tried introducing the for loop you can see but this then only checks if the object is intersecting another object one at a time so it can overlap with a previous one.

```
            if(i > 0) {
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    while ((atomXPosition[i] < atomXPosition[j] + atomWidth[j]
                            && atomXPosition[i] + atomWidth[i] > atomXPosition[j]
                            && atomYPosition[i] + atomWidth[i] > atomYPosition[j]
                            && atomYPosition[i] < atomYPosition[j] + atomWidth[j])) {
                        atomXPosition[i] = (float) Math.random() * (screenWidth - atomWidth[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Having a tough time visualizing this. can you show us some of your code that you've currently got

Comment: the conditions of the while loop don't seem to be uniform. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: All the conditions in the while loop need to be repeated for j between 0 and the number of objects already placed

Answer (score 1):

Why not have an Atom class?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Atom {

    private static final int NUM_ATOMS = 20;
    private static final int MAX_TRIES = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Atom> atoms = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ATOMS; i++) {
            Atom atom = new Atom();

            atoms.add(atom);

            for (int tries = 0; tries < MAX_TRIES; tries++) {
                if (atom.intersectsAny(atoms)) {
                    int randomX = //...
                    int randomY = //...
                    atom.moveTo(randomX, randomY);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public boolean intersectsAny(List<Atom> atoms) {
        return atoms.stream().anyMatch(this::intersects);
    }

    private boolean intersects(Atom other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return false;
        }

        return //... check if this atom intersects other atom
    }

    public void moveTo(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as the conditional within your `while` loop. This function could take something like an `ArrayList` as input, and you could add the object to the `ArrayList` every iteration of the `while` loop.